# How to separate a book in to chapters

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to separate a book in to chapters, the book is inside a text file. So far I have tried one method which isn't working very well.

Currently I'm storing each chapter within a String Array element, so chapter one will be in element 1 etc.. The problem is, it is giving me a outofbound error, here's the code:

```
public void separateChapters(String[] book){
    int x = 2;
    int y = 1;
    String temp = null;
    String ch = "2";
    while (y < 100){ 
        while (!verses[x].contains(("CHAPTER " + ch))) {//+ Integer.toString(x)

            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);

            temp = verses[x]+temp;
            chapters[y] = verses[x]+temp; //chapters is a global variable

            x++;
        } 
        y++;
        int toIncrement = Integer.parseInt(ch); //jump to next chapter
        toIncrement++;
        ch = Integer.toString(toIncrement);
    }
    System.out.println(chapters[1]);


}
```

This method stores the chapters correctly in each element, but while adding chapter 48 to its element I get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

I know my method is not so good, if someone could help me figure out a more efficient method, or correct this one it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating the `chapters` and `verses` arrays? Why do you start with `ch = "2"`? Shouldn't it be the first one, `ch = "1"` instead?

Comment: May be it will be more simple to use String.split("CHAPTER \d+") ? (In this case your book should be as String. not string array)

Comment: ch = "2" because while loops adds everything in element 1 until it reaches "CHAPTER 2", if you look at the while loop condition while hence (!verses[x].contains(("CHAPTER " + ch))). Once it reaches chapter 2, ch = 3, therefore will add everything to element 2 until it reach chapter 3 etc..

Comment: @chache: So I should add the whole book in one String, then split it in to chapters? I'm not familiar with this method but sounds much simpler.

Comment: Obviously you had to create `verses` before you call this method, and you had to give it an upper bound, something like `verses = new String[1000]`.  So you're probably just overflowing that.  Consider using an `ArrayList`, then you don't have to set an upper bound beforehand.  I'm assuming that you actually **want** an array of verses after you're done.  If you don't need to keep the verses afterwards, you don't need an array at all.

Comment: verses contains each paragraph of the text book, there're over 14,000 paragraphs. I want to know which chapter the paragraphs belong to, the whole purpose is to search and display specific paragraph from a chapter. I'm gonna add it all in one String then start splitting, I will see how far I get using that method, and if I succeed I will post the results. Meanwhile, I still don't understand why I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the above code?

Comment: You still haven't told us how you created the `verses` and `chapter` variables.  Also, please look at the stack trace and tell us exactly which line you're getting the exception on.  (Don't tell us the line number because the lines in your code example don't have numbers.)

Comment: Actually not "paragraph", but each sentence, I used Scanner to store each line on an ArrayList, then convert the ArrayList to StringArray, then tried to separate the StringArray in to Chapters using the above mentioned condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tried [cache's] method and it worked perfectly, I managed to separate the String in to chapters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String book;
    book= readFile("Book.txt",Charset.defaultCharset());

    String[] ch = book.split("CHAPTER");

    System.out.println(ch[2]); //prints chapter two
}
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
    throws IOException 
{
    byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
    return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> "so chapter one will be in element 1 ".
>   "adding chapter 48 to its element I get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException."

Arrays in Java start at index 0. A `String[48]` does not have an element at index 48, the last one is 47.

So you need to either put chapter one in position 0 (preferred), or make the array one element larger.

Comment: I understand that, I wanted each element to represent the chapter, that's why I started at element 1. The first element in my case returns null, which isn't a problem for me. The problem is, it gives ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at element 48. Just to add, 48 is not the last chapter, the last chapter is 100.